# What do I need to know to buy land and install a house?

Tags: united-states, first-time-home-buyer

I recently inherited some money and wish to buy a house (my first).  I have tentatively concluded that the way to go is to buy a vacant lot (there are always some on Craigslist) and a prefab house.

As I'll be paying cash, I won't have a banker at my elbow to make sure the teas are dotted and the eyes crossed.  This makes me nervous: there are unknown unknowns.

Presumably I can hire an expert. What is this expert's title?

Locale is Washington, USA.

Comment: A real estate attorney, a realtor and the Internet (to google what to look for when buying land).

Comment: Start of by checking whether you are even allowed to build there.  Don't be the mug who buys an over-priced plot of land, only to discover that the local plans don't allow houses there.

Comment: First thing to do is to check the jurisdiction(s) of the lot you intend to buy, to see whether pre-fab construction is even allowed. Then you will need to find out a lot of other things, like whether you will be connecting to municipal water & sewer, or will need a well & septic system.  A decent answer would take a book.  But you can make the land purchase contingent on obtaining the required permits...

Comment: They're in Washington. The entire state prohibits local bans on prefab homes: https://www.seattlepi.com/local/article/By-law-manufactured-homes-are-now-welcome-1174681.php so no problems with that. But, yes. You need to make sure you can actually build there. Also, make sure to check the local floodplain.

Comment: SE is for questions, not statements.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a policy that the *subject matter* of the question has to be stated in the *form* of a question.  Seems to me like a waste of (a few) bytes.

Comment: This is SE, not Jeopardy!